# Need a Query for Total Seconds taken for Each Mode>Process

Tags: sql, ms-access

Please help me create a query to get  the total Seconds taken to process for each process (Mode> Process) for todate

[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLvrr.png)[Don't Know how to paste as ASCII Table]

[Required Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoLSe.png) (but I need Details for a Specified Start_Date )

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: Could you please edit the image and give it in a ASCII Format.. I don't know how to do that. Please,...

Comment: Please post this to SQLFiddle - makes it much easier to work with - and your expected results. http://sqlfiddle.com/ Perhaps show what you've tried - we're not a code writing service.

Comment: What do you mean by work stream?

Comment: Please, if you don't know how to create an ascii table, research that first. Your question currently shows little effort.

Comment: @Ankit bajpai , Mode (is WorkStream)

Comment: Your column start_time and end_time contains only date format data. They must be in datetime format.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai. I have update the table. Please see the attachment

Comment: End_time still do not have the datetime format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
SELECT CBD.ModeofCommunication
      ,CBD.Process
      ,Count(CBD.Process) AS [Processed Count]
      ,Sum(DateDiff("s",CBD.Start_Time,CBD.End_T‌​ime)) AS Time_Taken 
FROM Current_Bot_Details CBD
WHERE Date = '10/04/2017'
GROUP BY CBD.ModeofCommunication
        ,CBD.Process;
```

Comment: I have reached up to this..

SELECT Current_Bot_Details.ModeofCommunication, Current_Bot_Details.Process, Count(Current_Bot_Details.Process) AS [Processed Count], Sum(DateDiff("s",[Current_Bot_Details]![Start_Time],[Current_Bot_Details]![End_Time])) AS Time_Taken
FROM Current_Bot_Details
GROUP BY Current_Bot_Details.ModeofCommunication, Current_Bot_Details.Process;

Comment: I have updated the Required table format.

It currently contains Seconds taken for each process in all dates. But i need it for a specific date. Can you help on this.

Comment: Yeah..! Got it correct.!. Thanks for he support @Ankit